# Python: how to optimize this code for better performance

Tags: python

I use this code to syllable a list of strings, I need to be able to speed up this code to pass some tests, any ideas to improve this code and make it faster?

```
def separate(word):
s = ""
L = []
voc = ['a','e','i','o','u','y','j']
for letter in word:
    if len(s) < 1:
        s += letter

    elif s[len(s) - 1] not in voc:
            s += letter
    elif s.startswith('aeiouyj'):
           s +=letter

    elif letter in voc:
                s += letter
    else:
        L.append(s)
        s = letter
L.append(s)
return L
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "syllable a list of strings"?

Comment: i use this code for syllables a text,i call this function in another function that leave whitespace,special chars and dots

Comment: Also, when calling your code on 'ultrices', it results in 'u', 'ltri', 'ces' which I suspect isn't correct. The whole splitting text into syllables might get tricky :-)

Comment: the code works good with the texts that i import and 
follows the rules of the task

Comment: I'm a bit doubtful - how large is the text file you run this on? I did a trial run on 57kb of Lorem Ipsum text and the speed with naively calling your function for every word was sub-second one. (basically the only thing slowing the code down was the print at the end) Additionally I have found several more words that are wrong at glance - e.g. ['sa','pie','n']. Furthermore a quick check at the syllabling in general suggests that it is not an easy problem.

Comment: Does the condition `s.startswith('aeiouyj')` 
will ever return true

Comment: No it doesn't. Just checked. It can be safely removed to speed up the code ^^. Also if replaced with what I think that was intended, e.g.:  `s[0] in 'aeiouyj'`, the code falls appart.

Comment: around 300 kb in 3 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Did some small misc adjustments.

```py
def separate(word):
    s=''
    L = []
    for letter in word:
        if s=='':
           s = letter
        elif s[-1] not in 'aeiouyj' or letter in 'aeiouyj':
             s += letter
        else:
            L.append(s)
            s = letter
    L.append(s)
    return L
```

Not sure if `s.startswith('aeiouyj')` is of any use in original code because it never going to be `True`.

Comment: It has no use and using it actually breaks the code in case of words starting with a vowel or j.

Comment: A bit of both. Yes, it speeds up the code. And yes, it shows nicely that the original code shouldn't work. (And I think it actually doesn't). No as it breaks the code 'definitely' (even more than it already was).

Answer (score 0):

```
def separate(word):
    s = ""
    L = []
    voc = ['a','e','i','o','u','y','j']
    s=word[0]
    for letter in word[1:]:
        if s[len(s) - 1] not in voc:
            s += letter
        elif letter in voc or s.startswith('aeiouyj'):
           s +=letter
        else:
            L.append(s)
            s = letter
    L.append(s)
    return L
```

After analysing the code, we can see that it is going into first if just in the beginning. So, we can skip this part. One more thing you can do bring the if before last else to the second place. After analysing a Harry Potter paragraph with  this program it enters into loops "1,2436,0,98,959" times respectively. The third if maybe eliminated too, since it never entered into this branch in my case.